# Send header with token that someone is logged in

Tags: angular, wordpress, api, ionic-framework

I've a question, I'm trying to build my first Ionic app.
I've a problem to send header to Wordpress that someone is logged in.

I add in core of app:

```
   validateAuthToken(token){
  let header : Headers = new Headers();
  header.append('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
  return this.http.post('https://example.net/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate?token=' + token,
    {}, {headers: header})
 }
```

And in my plugin at wordpress site I added this code:
(to see that when I will be logged out private post will show.

```
 if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'You are not currently logged in.', array( 'post_status' => 'private', 'show_in_rest'  => true ) );
    }
```

But I have error and my private post doesn't appear.

I want to create app that logged in user will see private post.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is WordPress unable to access the token? Make sure the token is being sent in network inspector tool

Comment: Try to send this request with postman and see if you can see the private data